# Keras model architecture model.add parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm pretty new to neural network and I'm trying to build a model that will get 2 inputs with a different shape(3668, 688 and 3668, 300) and the train output with a shape of (3668, 988).

I have 35 different classes which I need to predict.

I created this model which kind of work but without any reasonable improvement in the accuracy. I know that I'm definitely doing something wrong with the parameters I put in the model.add function but I'm not sure what should I put over there.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3668, input_dim=300, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(988, activation= K.exp))

offset = Sequential()
offset.add(Dense(988, input_dim=688, activation='linear'))

input1 = Input(shape=(300,))
input2 = Input(shape=(688,))
x1 = model(input1)
x2 = offset(input2)

from keras.layers import Multiply, add
output = Multiply()([x1, x2])

from keras.models import Model
modelnew = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)

modelnew.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])

modelnew.fit([categorical_train_data, numerical_train_data], train_outputs, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=5)
```

Can you please help me figure it out?

Comment: Well, you say absolutely nothing about what data are you using or what are you trying to achieve, makes it kind of hard to help you.  

Two things look weird to me:  
1. You are using three models to get a model with two inputs and one output; one model could do it all.  
2. You use `Multiply` layer to feed both inputs; my first reaction would be to use `Concatenate`

Comment: Sorry, you’re right. Out of a dataframe that I had, I created 2 datasets: one with dummy variables of some features and another one is a CountVector result that I created for a few text columns of the df. I started by merging them and to train a NN using this merged df, but I felt that it isn’t the right approach. So I’m trying to train a model on these two datasets to predict the right classification (35 in total), this is where I lost control basically :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this model:

```
# define two sets of inputs
inputA = Input(shape=(300,))
inputB = Input(shape=(688,))

# the first branch operates on the first input
x = Dense(300, activation="relu", use_bias=True)(inputA)
x = Dense(50, activation="relu", use_bias=True)(x)
x = Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)

# the second branch opreates on the second input
y = Dense(688, activation="relu", use_bias=True)(inputB)
y = Dense(300, activation="relu", use_bias=True)(y)
y = Dense(50, activation="relu", use_bias=True)(y)
y = Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)

# combine the output of the two branches
combined = Concatenate()([x.output, y.output])

# apply a FC layer and then a regression prediction on the
# combined outputs
z = Dense(100, input_dim=100, activation='relu', use_bias=True)(combined)
z = Dense(35, activation='sigmoid')(z)

# our model will accept the inputs of the two branches and
# then output a single value
model2 = Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=z)
model2.summary()
```

That I took from here: 
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

and I combined it with other models that I found. It works really well.